# ice:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, icefaces

I've only been using Ice:faces for a week now and I'm having problems figuring out how to implement a simple selectOneMenu to my page so I can select a gender of a person by a simple drop down rather then typing stuff in.

The error im getting is the following

---

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: data.SelectMenuHomes@ad503c.selectedGender(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent)

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 logs.

---

so i figured im obviously refering to something that isnt there

here is my code

In the page jsp form :

```
<ice:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{homeSelect.selectedGender}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{homeSelect.genders}"/>
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

the class for the select menu :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;


public class SelectMenuHomes
{
    public static String selectedGender = null;


    public static void changeGender(ValueChangeEvent event)
    {
    selectedGender = event.getNewValue().toString();
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getGenders()
    {
        List<SelectItem> genderList = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();
        genderList.add(new SelectItem("Male"));
        genderList.add(new SelectItem("Female"));
        return genderList;
    }


    public String getSelectedGender() {
        return selectedGender;
    }

    public void setSelectedGender(String selectedGender) {
        this.selectedGender = selectedGender;
    }

}
```

and homeSelect is the name for the managed bean I gave to refer to the MenuSelectHomesClass

thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
<ice:selectOneMenu value="#{dataControl.appendGender}"> 
<f:selectItems value= "#{homeSelect.genders}"/> 
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

appendGender is the variable used in the method to run the SQL query along with variables like appendName appendSurname etc etc

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the method called by the valueChangedListener. valueChangeListener="#{homeSelect.selectedGender}" in your jsf file points to a method "selectedGender(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent)" in your homeSelect bean which is missing. You are not using the value= attribute.

You cant put objects directly in these menus without a converter or utility.

see "Use Objects in selectMenu": http://balusc.blogspot.ch/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html
also have a look at: http://omnifaces.org which comes along with such a [converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter).

Comment: so am I going to have to create a seperate gender class for this to work?

currently I have a java class to run functions needed by the jsp, the jsp class itself, the xml configuration class and a PersonInfo class containing getters and setters for the names surnames address etc etc

Comment: Hmmmm
Not in any case. Standard types like String and so on work out of the box. If the gender remains a string you should not even need the valuechangelistener. a simple value= binding to personInfo.gender should work in this case too.

Comment: Solved 

 <ice:selectOneMenu value="#{dataControl.appendGender}">

                                        <f:selectItems value= "#{homeSelect.genders}"/>

appendGender is the variable used in the method to run the SQL query along with variables like appendName appendSurname etc etc

Thank you for your help 

                                    </ice:selectOneMenu>